# How to extract multiple columns, one being unique values from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm having a blonde moment,  I have a timestamp and value column that I want to query from a PHP MySQL table "mytable".
However I would like only get one value and the *corresponding* timestamp for the one value. For example:

```
value,timestamp
23,2016-09-01 00:04:05 
23,2016-09-01 00:04:05 
23,2016-09-02 01:04:05 < --- extract this
24,2016-09-02 01:05:13
24,2016-09-03 01:04:24 
27,2016-09-03 03:24:34 
27,2016-09-04 04:24:42
27,2016-09-05 05:54:12 
27,2016-09-06 00:04:05
27,2016-09-07 00:04:05 < --- extract this
28,2016-09-08 00:04:05 < --- extract this
```

I want to be able to extract from the above table, one`value` and it's corresponding `timestamp`

```
value,timestamp
23,2016-09-02 01:04:05
27,2016-09-07 00:04:05
28,2016-09-08 00:04:05
```

**Q:** What would be the query look like?

Comment: How are those unique? I don't see any pattern in what you want to output.

Comment: I also don't see any pattern, but this looks like this might be a gaps and islands problem.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, my apologies, I fixed up my question, I just want the latest time stamp with a one-off value i.e no duplicate values... again my apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
    value,
    MAX(TIMESTAMP)
FROM
    yourTable
GROUP BY
    value
```